# How to change how Hadoop v1.x handles stragglers

Tags: hadoop

I recently have been learning about Hadoop v1.x and am trying to implement an algorithm I came across in a research paper. This algorithm investigates the straggler tasks to see if they indeed need to be killed and restarted or they just need more time. Would someone please point me in the right direction of where in the Hadoop source code I can implement this algorithm?

I have searched parameters and .java classes deep into the Hadoop v1.x source code download to try to and find where the logic is to kill tasks, but to no avail. I am also currently not very strong in my Java skills but I know enough to get by.

Here is the pseudo-code algorithm:

```
procedure RTUNER (Task T[])   
  for RT in T do        
    if RT in reduce then 
      flag=CHECKFORSTRAGGLER(RT) 
      REASONFORSTRAGGLER(RT) 
      decision=CHECKFORSPECULATION(RT)              
      if decision=true and CROSSSPECULATIVELIMIT()=false      
        then SPECULATE(RT) 
      end if
    end if
  end for 
end procedure
```

Comment: Why are you using Hadoop 1.x?  Anyway, in Hadoop this feature is called `speculative.execution`, you can search on that in the code.

Comment: Thank you, @tk421. From what I understand, Hadoop v2 has replaced the TaskTracker. Is there a way to use this algorithm in Hadoop v2?